# How to set different JTextArea text alignment per line?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTextArea in which i want to display messages aligned to right or left, depending on a variable I pass along with the message. Can I do that?

---

What did I do wrong? Nothing gers added to the text pane when i run my GUI

```
battleLog = new JTextPane();
    StyledDocument bL = battleLog.getStyledDocument();

    SimpleAttributeSet r = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(r, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);

    try {
        bL.insertString(bL.getLength(), "test", r);
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with a JTextArea.

You need to use a `JTextPane` which supports different text and paragraph attributes. An example to CENTER the text:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText("Line1");
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

//  Define the attribute you want for the line of text

SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

//  Add some text to the end of the Document

try
{
    int length = doc.getLength();
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\ntest", null);
    doc.setParagraphAttributes(length+1, 1, center, false);
}
catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e);}
```

Comment: Does `JtextPane` accept user inputs as `JTextArea` does?

Comment: This does not work for me, nothing gets added to the text pane. See the edit in question please.

Comment: @Braj, it is like a JTextArea except it supports attributes for the text. See the Swing tutorial on [Text Components Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a more complete example of its ability to use attributes.

Comment: @Asalas77, Oops, the alignment attribute is a paragraph attribute so you need to set it for the whole line, not just the string you are inserting. See the code for an updated example.

Answer (score 0):

```
if("left".equals(input)){
    setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
}
```

Have  a try!

Comment: wouldn't rhis change the alignment of all the lines currently in my text area? I only need to change the last one and keep the rest as it was.

Comment: The setAlignmentX(...) method is used for aligning the entire component in its parent panel, if the layout manager supports the alignment property. It has nothing to do with the text inside the text pane.